# Showing that degree of polynomial reduced modulo $p$ divides degree of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, contest-math, galois-theory

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer coefficients and $p$ a prime for which $f$, considered modulo $p$, is a degree-$k$ irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Show that $k$ divides the degree of the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(this is Miklos Schweitzer 2020, Problem 10)

**My miscellaneous thoughts:** We know that for a polynomial of degree $n$, the degree of its splitting field is at most $n!$ from induction on the Ring Tower Theorem. Additionally, since $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then the field $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ has a root of $f(x)$. Now suppose $k = 2$. Then $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ reduces to $f(x) \equiv b_2 x^2 + b_1x + b_0 \in \mathbb{F}_p [x]$ where $b_i \equiv a_i \pmod{p}$ where applicable. I'm really not sure if these things are particularly useful or how to combine them.

This is really hard!

Answer (score 3):

Cool problem! Here is a solution, which I preface with a hint/sketch, in case anyone reading wants to try to finish it for themself.

First fix some notation: let $\overline{f}$ be the reduction of $f$ mod $p$, $K/\mathbb{Q}$ the splitting field of $f$, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{p}$ any prime of $\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $p$ and $e$ its ramification index.

The hint/sketch: since $\overline{f}$ is irreducible, its splitting field $\kappa$ has degree $k$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. We'd like to exhibit $\operatorname{Gal}(\kappa/\mathbb{F}_p)$ as a subquotient of the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ via a map from the decomposition group $D(\mathfrak p)$, so then $k\mid |\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})|=[K:F]$. The trouble is that $f$ is not monic, so it may not have roots in $\mathcal{O}_K$ (or even in the localization $(\mathcal{O}_K)_\mathfrak{p}$), and so it's not immediate that the factorization of $f$ in $K$ gives rise to a factorization of $\overline{f}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$. The idea will be to use Vieta's formulas and an extension of the $p$-adic valuation to show that there are exactly $k$ roots of $f$ giving rise to the roots of $\overline{f}$ (namely, roots of $f$ with denominators not in $\mathfrak{p}$).

The solution: we shift attention to the localization $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$, and let $\nu:=\nu_{\mathfrak p}$ be the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation, so $\nu(x)=e\nu_p(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Write $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i.$$
Then the hypotheses imply: (1) $\nu(a_i)>0$ for $i>k$; (2) $\nu(a_k)=0$; (3) $\nu(a_0)=0$. Here (1) and (2) are immediate and (3) follows by noting that $\overline{f}$ has no constant term otherwise, which would imply $\overline{f}$ has a root $x=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (so it is either reducible or has degree $1$). Let $r_i=c_i/d_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$ be the roots of $f$ in $K$, with $c_i,d_i\in (\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ not both in $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $R=\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}$. For $0\leq \ell \leq n-1$, Vieta's formulas can be written
$$
a_\ell = (-1)^{n-\ell}\cdot a_n\cdot \sum_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-\ell}\prod_{r_i\in \sigma}r_i.
$$
Furthermore, we have $a_n=\prod_{i=1}^nd_i$. In particular, $a_0=\prod_{i=1}^nd_i\cdot \prod_{i=1}^nr_i$ is the product of the numerators $c_i$, and (3) above then gives $\nu(c_i)=0$ for all $i$, so $\nu(r_i)=-\nu(d_i)$. Writing this out for $a_k$ and applying $\nu$ gives
$$
0=\nu(a_k) = \nu(a_n)+\nu\left(\sum_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-k}\prod_{r_i\in \sigma}r_i\right).
$$
Recall the **Strong Triangle Inequality:** $\nu(\sum_{finite} x_i)\geq \min_i(\nu(x_i))$ with equality unless $\min_i(\nu(x_i))=\nu(x_i)=\nu(x_j)$ for some $i\neq j$.
Applied above, this gives
$$
0=\nu(a_n)+\nu\left(\sum_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-k}\prod_{r_i\in \sigma}r_i\right)\geq \nu(a_n)+\min_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-k}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}\nu(r_i)\right).
$$
Rearranging and applying $\nu(r_i)=-\nu(d_i)$ gives
$$
\nu(a_n)\leq-\min_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-k}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}-\nu(d_i)\right)=\max_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-k}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}\nu(d_i)\right).
$$
But $\nu(a_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\nu(d_i)$, so we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\nu(d_i)\leq\max_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-k}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}\nu(d_i)\right),$$
and we see that there can be at most $n-k$ values of $i$ for which $\nu(d_i)>0$, otherwise the left hand side will be larger than the right.

Now we claim that there are exactly $n-k$ values of $i$ for which $\nu(d_i)>0$. Suppose otherwise, so that there are exactly $\ell>k$ values of $i$ with $\nu(d_i)=0$. Then observe that, in the formula
$$
\nu(a_\ell) = \nu(a_n)+\nu\left(\sum_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-\ell}\prod_{r_i\in \sigma}r_i\right)
$$
there is a **unique** term in the sum on the right with minimal valuation, namely $\prod_{r_i:\nu(r_i)\neq 0}r_i$, so the strong triangle inequality will give an equality, and we have
$$
\nu(a_\ell) = \nu(a_n)+\min_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-\ell}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}\nu(r_i)\right)=\nu(a_n)+\min_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-\ell}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}-\nu(d_i)\right)=\nu(a_n)-\max_{\sigma\subset R\atop |\sigma|=n-\ell}\left(\sum_{r_i\in \sigma}\nu(d_i)\right)=\sum_{r_i:\nu(r_i)\neq 0}\nu(d_i)-\sum_{r_i:\nu(r_i)\neq 0}\nu(d_i)=0
$$
contradicting (1) above, since $\ell>k$. Thus there are exactly $n-k$ values of $i$ with $\nu(d_i)>0$, and so after reindexing the roots $r_i$, we can write the (non-monic) factorization of $f$ over $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as
$$
f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(x-c_i)\cdot \prod_{i=k+1}^{n}(d_ix-c_i).
$$
Let $g(x):=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(x-c_i)\in (\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$, and $\overline{g}$ its image in $((\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p})[x]$. Notice that $\overline{f}(x)=\prod_{i=k+1}^nc_i\cdot \overline{g}(x)$. In particular, $\overline{f}$ splits over $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}$!

Now we're in the home stretch: $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}$ contains the splitting field $\kappa$ of $\overline{f}$, so letting $I(\mathfrak p)$ denote the inertia group at $\mathfrak{p}$ we conclude via $$k=[\kappa:\mathbb{F}_p]\mid [((\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}):\kappa][\kappa:\mathbb{F}_p]=[((\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}):\mathbb{F}_p]=\#\operatorname{Gal}(((\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p})/\mathbb{F}_p)=\#D(\mathfrak{p})/\#I(\mathfrak{p})\mid \#D(\mathfrak{p})\mid \#\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=[K:\mathbb{Q}].$$

Comment: Your condition (ii) should be $v(a_k) = 0$.

Comment: @KCd fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with a hint/sketch as Quinn does in his answer, if someone wants to try this before reading the details: factor $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$  (*not* just in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$) using Hensel's lemma or Newton polygons to get a factor of degree $k$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ that has an irreducible reduction mod $p$ of degree $k$. Then think of the Galois group of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf Q_p$ as a decomposition group at a prime ideal over $p$ in the integers of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf Q$.

We will use the decomposition group at a prime ideal, as Quinn does in the other solution posted here, but we'll interpret decomposition groups as Galois groups of $\mathfrak p$-adic completions.  This has the advantage that a decomposition group is genuinely a Galois group over $\mathbf Q_p$ *even* in the case of ramified primes, whereas if you work with localizations then you can say $D(\mathfrak p|p)/I(\mathfrak p|p)$ is a Galois group over $\mathbf F_p$ but you can't say that about $D(\mathfrak p|p)$ itself for *all* $p$.

The first step is to factor $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ into a factor of degree $k$ and a complementary factor, where the first factor reduces mod $p$ to an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbf F_p[x]$.  I will show two ways to do this: by Hensel's lemma and by Newton polygons.

**Method 1**: Factoring $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ by Hensel's lemma.

We are going to use a version of Hensel's lemma in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ that allows for polynomials whose leading coefficients are not $p$-adic units. Here is the version I have in mind.

**Theorem**:  *Let $f(x) \in \mathbf Z_p[x]$ with at least one coefficient being in $\mathbf Z_p^\times$, and assume the reduced polynomial $\overline{f}(x)$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ can be written as $\alpha(x)\beta(x)$ where $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ are relatively prime polynomials in $\mathbf F_p[x]$. Then in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ we can write $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ where (i) $\overline{a}(x) = \alpha(x)$ and $\overline{b}(x) = \beta(x)$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ and (ii) $\deg a(x) = \deg \alpha(x)$.*

*Proof*: See Gouvea, "$p$-Adic Numbers: an Introduction" (2nd ed.) Theorem 3.4.6, p. 72 or Borevich and Shafarevich, "Number Theory," Theorem 2, p. 275 for a proof.

**Remark**. I am using the hypotheses as they appear in Borevich and Shafarevich. Gouvea instead essentially assumes $\alpha(x)$ is monic and says in the conclusion that $a(x)$ is monic, but that is morally the same kind of condition as $\deg a(x) = \deg \alpha(x)$ in the theorem above.

Note $\overline{f}(x)$ is not $0$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ since some coefficient of $f(x)$ (not necessarily the leading coefficient!) is in $\mathbf Z_p^\times$.

We are *not* requiring $\deg b(x) = \deg \beta(x)$, and the following example illustrates that.

**Example**. In $\mathbf Z_2[x]$ let $f(x) = 6x^5 + 4x^3 + x^2 + x + 3$. Then in $\mathbf F_2[x]$, $\overline{f}(x) = x^2+x+1$, which is irreducible and the degree has dropped from $5$ down to $2$. We can write $\overline{f}(x)$ in $\mathbf F_2[x]$ as a product of relatively prime factors $\alpha(x)\beta(x)$ in two ways, and each lifts to a corresponding factorization of $f(x)$ as $a(x)b(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_2[x]$ where $\deg a(x) = \deg \alpha(x)$.

First way: $\alpha(x) = 1$ and $\beta(x) = x^2+x+1$. Then we can use $a(x) = 1$ and $b(x) = f(x)$. Indeed, $f(x) = 1 \cdot f(x)$, $\overline{1}(x) = \alpha(x)$, $\overline{f}(x) = \beta(x)$, and $\deg a(x) = \deg \alpha(x)$ (but $\deg b(x) = 6 \not= \deg \beta(x))$. This is how the theorem looks when we use $\alpha(x) = 1$. It is silly, but it is valid.

Second way: $\alpha(x) = x^2+x+1$ and $\beta(x) = 1$. Then the theorem says $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_2[x]$ where $\overline{a}(x) = x^2+x+1$, $\overline{b}(x) = 1$, and $\deg a(x) = 2$ (but $\deg b(x) = 3 \not= \deg \beta(x)$). Using PARI,
$$
a(x) = x^2 + (1 + 2 + 2^5 + 2^{15} + 2^{16} + \cdots)x + (1 + 2^2 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^{10} + 2^{13} + 2^{16} + \cdots)
$$
and
$$
b(x) = 6x^3 + (2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^8 + 2^9 + 2^{10} + 2^{11} + 2^{12} + 2^{13} + 2^{14} + 2^{15} + \cdots)x^2 + (2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^6 + 2^9 + 2^{14} + 2^{16} + \cdots)x + (1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^6 + 2^{11} + 2^{14} + 2^{15} + \cdots).
$$
Notice $\overline{a}(x) = x^2+x+1$ and $\overline{b}(x) = 1$ in $\mathbf F_2[x]$.  This concludes the example.

We'll now apply Hensel's lemma to the contest problem. We are told $f(x) \in \mathbf Z[x]$ has degree $n$ and $\overline{f}(x) = \pi(x)$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ is irreducible of degree $k$, so $1 \leq k \leq n$. Use Hensel's lemma with $\alpha(x) = \pi(x)$ and $\beta(x) = 1$, as in the "second way" of the example above.  We obtain $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ where $\overline{a}(x) = \pi(x)$, $\overline{b}(x) = 1$, and $\deg a(x) = \deg \pi(x) = k$. That means $a(x)$ has a leading coefficient in $\mathbf Z_p^\times$, since its degree did not drop under reduction mod $p$. So $a(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ whose reduction mod $p$ is irreducible of degree $k$.

**Method 2**:  Factoring $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ by Newton polygons.

By the hypotheses of the problem, the constant term $f(0)$ is not divisible by $p$, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $f(x)$ is not divisible by $p$, coefficients of $f(x)$ of degree strictly between $0$ and $k$ may or may not be divisible by $p$ (but at least they are integral) and the coefficients of $f(x)$ of degree greater than $k$ are all divisible by $p$. Therefore the first segment of the $p$-adic Newton polygon of $f(x)$ is the segment on the $x$-axis from $(0,0)$ to $(k,0)$. Further segments of the $p$-adic Newton polygon of $f(x)$ have positive slope, so $f(x)$ has $k$ roots in $\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$ with $p$-adic absolute value $1$ ($p$-adic valuation $0$) and its other roots in $\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$ have $p$-adic absolute value greater than $1$.

Numbers algebraic over $\mathbf Q_p$ that are roots of the same irreducible polynomial in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$ have the same $p$-adic absolute value, so the $k$ roots of $p$-adic absolute value $1$ are $\mathbf Q_p$-conjugate only to other roots of $p$-adic absolute value $1$. Therefore if we let $a(x)$ be the product of the monic irreducible factors of $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$  whose roots have $p$-adic absolute value $1$,  then $\deg a(x) = k$, $a(x)$ is in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ (not just $\mathbf Q_p[x]$!) and $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ where $b(x) \in \mathbf Q_p[x]$.  We want to show $b(x) \in \mathbf Z_p[x]$. Since $a(x)$ is monic in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ and $f(x) \in \mathbf Z_p[x]$, we can apply the division algorithm in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ to write $f(x) = a(x)q(x) + r(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ where $r(x) = 0$ or $\deg r(x) < k$.
Viewing this in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$ and comparing it to $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$, the uniqueness of the division algorithm  in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$  tells us that $q(x) = b(x)$ and $r(x) = 0$. Therefore $b(x) \in \mathbf Z_p[x]$, so the factorization $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ is in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$. Why is $a(x) \bmod p$ irreducible in $\mathbf F_p[x]$?

Reduce the equation $f(x) = a(x)b(x)$ modulo $p$: in $\mathbf F_p[x]$, $\overline{f}(x) = \overline{a}(x)\overline{b}(x)$. Since $a(x)$ is monic of degree $k$, $\overline{a}(x)$ has degree $k$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$. By the hypothesis of the problem, $\overline{f}(x)$ is irreducible of degree $k$.    Therefore by unique factorization in $\mathbf F_p[x]$, $\overline{a}(x)$ is irreducible and $\overline{b}(x)$ is a nonzero constant.

Now we continue with the rest of the argument, knowing (by two methods) that $f(x)$ factors as $a(x)b(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ where $a(x) \bmod p$ is irreducible of degree $k$.  By the reduction mod $p$ test, $a(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$.

Let $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be a full set of roots of $f(x)$ in an extension of $\mathbf Q_p$.  Then $\mathbf Q_p(r_1, \ldots, r_n)$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf Q_p$ and $K := \mathbf Q(r_1, \ldots, r_n)$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf Q$.  We want to show $k \mid [K:\mathbf Q]$.

Some $r_i$ is a root of $a(x)$, so $[\mathbf Q_p(r_i):\mathbf Q_p] = \deg a(x) = k$ on account of irreducibility of $a(x)$ over $\mathbf Q_p$. Therefore $k$ divides $[\mathbf Q_p(r_1,\ldots,r_n):\mathbf Q_p]$.

Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal lying over $p$ in $\mathcal O_K$. Then the $\mathfrak p$-adic completion $K_{\mathfrak p}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf Q_p(r_1,\ldots, r_n)$. (Since $K/\mathbf Q$ is Galois, its completions at different prime ideals lying over $p$ are isomorphic as extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$, so the specific choice of $\mathfrak p$ lying over $p$ is not important; any one is as good as any other.) The extension $K_{\mathfrak p}/\mathbf Q_p$ is Galois and ${\rm Gal}(K_{\mathfrak p}/\mathbf Q_p)$ is isomorphic to the decomposition group $D(\mathfrak p|p)$ in ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$. From the "$efg = n$" formula for Galois extensions of number fields, $|{\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)|$ is divisible by $|D(\mathfrak p|p)|$, so $[K:\mathbf Q]$ is divisible by $|{\rm Gal}(K_{\mathfrak p}/\mathbf Q_p)|$, which equals $[K_{\mathfrak p}:\mathbf Q_p]$, and that is divisible by $k$. Thus $k \mid [K:\mathbf Q]$.

In fact, since $a(x)$ has an irreducible reduction mod $p$, each root of $r$ of $a(x)$ generates an unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$, so $[\mathbf Q_p(r):\mathbf Q_p]$ divides the degree of the residue field extension for $K_{\mathfrak p}/\mathbf Q_p$. Residue field degrees do not change under completion, so $k$ divides $f(\mathfrak p|p)$, which is also what Quinn found at the end of his answer ($k \mid [(\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p:\mathbf F_p]$).

Боже мой, какая замечательная задача!

Answer (score 2):

If $p\mid f(0)$ then $\overline f(x)=cx$ (using the notation from the previous posts) for some $c\in\mathbb F_p^\times$, and thus $k=1$. So let's assume $p\nmid f(0)$ from now on. Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be the roots of $f(x)$ in $K$ and let * denotes the reciprocal polynomial. Then $f^*(x)$ has degree $n$ (since $f(0)\ne0$) and roots $1/x_1,\ldots,1/x_n$. Furthermore, we have $f(0)/x_1,\ldots,f(0)/x_n\in\mathcal O_K$ since they are roots of the monic polynomial $g(x):=f(0)^{n-1}\cdot f^*(x/f(0))\in\mathbb Z[x]$. Let $\mathfrak P$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ above $p$, then since $g(x)$ splits in $\mathcal O_K$, $\overline g(x)$ splits in $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak P$. We have $\overline{f^*}(x)=x^{n-k}\cdot\overline f^*(x)$, and since $p\nmid f(0)$, $\overline f^*(x)$ has degree $k$ and is irreducible over $\mathbb F_p$, and $\overline g(x)=\overline{f(0)}^{k-1}x^{n-k}\cdot\overline f^*\big(x/\overline{f(0)}\big)$. The polynomial $\overline f^*\big(x/\overline{f(0)}\big)$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb F_p$ of degree $k$, and thus the splitting field of $\overline g(x)$ is just $\mathbb F_p[x]\big/\big(\overline f^*\big(x/\overline{f(0)}\big)\big)$ and
$$k=\big[\mathbb F_p[x]\big/\big(\overline f^*\big(x/\overline{f(0)}\big)\big):\mathbb F_p\big]\mid\big[\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak P:\mathbb F_p\big]\mid\big[K:\mathbb Q\big].$$

Comment: Hard to read but looking at (the minimal polynomial of) $f(0)/x_1$ (which is in $O_K$) is clearly a good idea.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for editing my post on the Riemann sphere projection to fix my accidental swap in reasons. I'm not sure why your edit was rejected by other users but I've restored your fix! =)

Answer (score 1):

$f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ is such that $f\bmod p$ is irreducible and non-constant. Factorize $f=\prod_j f_j\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$, then one of the $f_j$ is such that $f_j=c f\bmod p$ with $c\in \Bbb{F}_p^\times$.

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ so that $f_j$ has a root $a/b\in Frac(O_L)$.

Note that $p$ is not a unit of $\Bbb{Z}[a/b]\cong\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f_j)$. Since $O_L[a/b]$ is integral over $\Bbb{Z}[a/b]$ it means that $O_L[a/b]$ contains a maximal ideal $P$ above $p$.

Being finite fields $O_L[a/b]/P$ contains and is integral over $O_L/(P\cap O_L)$, thus $a/b\in (O_L)_{(P\cap O_L)}$ and $O_L/(P\cap O_L)\cong O_L[a/b]/P$.

So $O_L/(P\cap O_L)$ contains $\Bbb{Z}[a/b]/(p) \cong \Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$.

Thus $\deg(f\bmod p)$ divides $[O_L/(P\cap O_L):\Bbb{F}_p]$.

The factorization $pO_L = \prod_j Q_j^e$ with $Q_1=P\cap O_L$ and $N(Q_j)=N(Q_1)=p^{[O_L/(P\cap O_L):\Bbb{F}_p]}, N(pO_L)=p^{[L:\Bbb{Q}]}$ gives that $\deg(f\bmod p)$ divides $[L:\Bbb{Q}]$.

Comment: If $f\bmod p$ is not irreducible then the degree of its splitting field will divide that of $f$.

Comment: We can assume $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ here, so effectively $f=f_j$. Why does $\mathcal{O}_L$ contain $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$? If $f$ isn't monic then its roots might not be integral.

Comment: @QuinnGreicius Tks I repaired

Comment: Why is $(p)$ still maximal (or prime, etc.) in $\mathbb{Z}[a/b]$? I'm wondering about the case where $b\in (p)$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[a/b]/(p)\cong\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f_j)/(p)=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$